# After migrate Camunda 7.4 to 7.5 (wildfiy 10), camunda-welcome.war is not loaded

Tags: java, jboss, camunda

I am working on my camunda migration from 7.4 (Wildfly) to 7.5 (Wildfly 10) by using migration tool as link: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/CMTOOL/WildFly+8+to+10 and correct some configuration based on this link: [post in below comment, url_1].

After everything was done, i can start up the service with no error but when i open the URL --> [post in below comment, url_2], i got error 404 but when i access to [post in below comment, url_3], i can access to the wildfly page normally.

I checked in server.log there was not log about this 404 but i did compare and found out that it did not load one of the .war folder (camunda-welcome.war which is under the path `.server/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments` , please see below log file: You can see that all files under `/deployments/` got loaded excepts `camunda-welcome.war` folder.

```
07:50:41,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
07:50:41,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
07:50:41,070 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/camunda/jboss_7.5/deploy-package/./server/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
07:50:41,079 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
07:50:41,082 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
07:50:41,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
07:50:41,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /camunda/jboss_7.5/deploy-package/./server/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
07:50:41,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "camunda-example-invoice-7.5.1-ee.war" (runtime-name: "camunda-example-invoice-7.5.1-ee.war")
07:50:41,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "camunda-webapp-ee-jboss-7.5.1-ee.war" (runtime-name: "camunda-webapp-ee-jboss-7.5.1-ee.war")
07:50:41,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "camunda-h2-webapp-7.5.1-ee.war" (runtime-name: "camunda-h2-webapp-7.5.1-ee.war")
07:50:41,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "camunda-engine-rest-7.5.1-ee.war" (runtime-name: "camunda-engine-rest-7.5.1-ee.war")
07:50:41,620 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
07:50:41,807 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
07:50:41,959 INFO  [org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.deployment.processor.ProcessApplicationProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Detected user-provided @ProcessApplication component with name 'org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication'.
07:50:42,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine]
07:50:42,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
07:50:42,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/mydatabaseDS]
```

Thanks in advance for your guys kind support in advance :).

Miss Sumana W.

Comment: url_1 : https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/minor/74-to-75/jboss/   url_2: http://localhost:8080/camunda-welcome/index.html                                url_3: http://10.1.1.159:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Updated::

I could migrate from version 7.4 to 7.5.0 (7.5.2 will give me above issue even before i did the migrate).. I had opened the issue to Camunda team..

Still open to any comments here. :)

Sumana W.

Answer (score 0):

Add an update.. i did open the case to camunda and to fix above issue is simply you need to just create a empty file called "camunda-welcome.war.dodeploy" under .server/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments and restart the service.. it will push camunda service to roll the camunda-welcome.war.deployed.. and now the site is load as expected :).